# Vertical menu sliding animation doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, css, menu, navigation, css-transitions

I was working on a vertical menu navigation but when the menu is hovered the vertical line doesn't slide on the right place. Also, when it's clicked the vertical line won't stay. Does anyone have a solution for these bugs?

```js
function selectNav(get_this){
  $('#sticky li').removeClass('selected');
  get_this.classList.add('selected');
}
```

```css
.in-page-menu > .in-page-menu li{

  line-height: 2em;
  height: 2em;

}

.in-page-menu > .in-page-menu li > .in-page-menu li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 2em;
}

.in-page-menu li:last-child::after, li.selected::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(255, 99, 71, 0.6);
  height: 2.5em;
  margin-top: 15px;
  left: 40px;
  width: .2em;
  top: 0;
  transition: all ease-in-out .2s;
  right: 0;
}
.in-page-menu li.selected::after{
  transform: translateY(-2.5em);
}
.in-page-menu li:nth-child(1):hover ~ li:last-child::after {
  transform:translateY(0.5em) !important;
}

.in-page-menu li:nth-child(2):hover ~ li:last-child::after {
  transform:translateY(83px) !important;

}
.in-page-menu li:nth-child(2).selected ~  li:last-child::after {
  transform:translateY(83px) !important;
}

.in-page-menu li:nth-child(3):hover ~  li:last-child::after {
  transform:translateY(7.5em) !important;
}
.in-page-menu li:nth-child(3).selected ~  li:last-child::after {
  transform:translateY(7.5em);
}
.in-page-menu li:nth-child(4):hover ~  li:last-child::after {
  transform:translateY(10.5em) !important;
}
.in-page-menu li:nth-child(4).selected ~  li:last-child::after {
  transform:translateY(10.5em);
}
.in-page-menu li:nth-child(5):hover ~  li:last-child::after {
  transform:translateY(237px) !important;
}
.in-page-menu li:nth-child(5).selected ~  li:last-child::after {
  transform:translateY(237px);
}

.in-page-menu--vertical a{
  margin-left: -1px;
  border-left: 2px solid #eae8e7;
  padding: 0.625em 0 1.625em 1.0625em;
}
.in-page-menu a{
  font-family: 'montserratlight', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  color: #767676;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: block;
  transition: all 150ms;
}

.in-page-menu-vertical a{
  margin-left: -1px;
  border-left: 3px solid transparent;
  padding: 0.625em 0 0.625em 1.0625em;
}

.in-page-menu a{
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transition: all 150ms;
  transition: all 150ms;
}
```

```html
<ul class="in-page-menu in-page-menu--vertical" id="sticky">
                <li onclick="selectNav(this)">
                  <a class="sticky-menu-link" href="#change-content">Change your content web easily</a>
                </li>
                <li onclick="selectNav(this)">
                  <a class="sticky-menu-link" href="#manage-order">Manage your order</a>
                </li>
                <li onclick="selectNav(this)">
                  <a class="sticky-menu-link" href="#inventory">Inventory management</a>
                </li>
                <li onclick="selectNav(this)">
                  <a class="sticky-menu-link" href="#manage-relationship">Manage your relationship</a>
                </li>
                <li onclick="selectNav(this)">
                  <a class="sticky-menu-link" href="#bcommerce">B2B commerce</a>
                </li>
                <li></li>
</ul>
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/pdbj86v5/)

So, I would like it to look like this: [SHOPIFY](https://www.shopify.co.id/pos/features#store-management)

I've also made the demo on jsfiddle. Thank you so much!
Your help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were multiple issues with your code. Here they are and the solution to them:

1. You didn't include jQuery into your snippet (perhaps it was just on this site and not with your code). Included.
2. You have mixed `em` with `px`. That is never a good idea. Fixes:

   - for the `.in-page-menu li` items, I made sure that their height is consistent by adding `box-sizing: border-box`, this will include any padding and border into the height calculation, otherwise it won't.
   - replaced all the `px` sizes with `em`, and made an educated guess about the positions. It might not be accurate, but it looks good for these items.
3. You always moved the vertical line which has been used for the hover.

   - fixed it by removing the `~ li:last-child` part from the `selected` class selector. This makes sure, that the selected menu item will always have a vertical line.
4. The Javascript had many issues. Fixed by:

   - using jQuery `addClass` function to add the `selected` class.
   - changed the selector for the `removeClass` line to find a match

**Notes**

- Added some styling to initially hide the hover vertical line. If you wish to have a line when the page loads, add a selected class to the desired menu item.
- If you intend to change your menu item heights, you will have to update the `translateY` positions as well.

**Working demo**

```js
function selectNav(get_this){
  $('li.selected').removeClass('selected');
  $(get_this).addClass('selected');
}
```

```css
.in-page-menu{
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.in-page-menu > .in-page-menu li{
  line-height: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.in-page-menu > .in-page-menu li > .in-page-menu li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 2em;
}

.in-page-menu li:last-child::after, li.selected::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(255, 99, 71, 0.6);
  height: 2.5em;
  margin-top: 15px;
  left: 8px;
  width: .2em;
  top: 0;
  transition: all ease-in-out .2s;
  right: 0;
}

.in-page-menu li:last-child::after {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.in-page-menu li:hover ~ li:last-child::after {
  visibility: visible;
}

.in-page-menu li:nth-child(1):hover ~ li:last-child::after {
  transform:translateY(0) !important;
}

.in-page-menu li:nth-child(1).selected::after{
  transform: translateY(0) !important;
}

.in-page-menu li:nth-child(2):hover  ~ li:last-child::after{
  transform:translateY(3em) !important;

}
.in-page-menu li:nth-child(2).selected::after {
  transform:translateY(3em) !important;
}

.in-page-menu li:nth-child(3):hover ~  li:last-child::after {
  transform:translateY(6em) !important;
}
.in-page-menu li:nth-child(3).selected::after {
  transform:translateY(6em);
}
.in-page-menu li:nth-child(4):hover ~  li:last-child::after {
  transform:translateY(9em) !important;
}
.in-page-menu li:nth-child(4).selected::after {
  transform:translateY(9em);
}
.in-page-menu li:nth-child(5):hover ~  li:last-child::after {
  transform:translateY(12em) !important;
}
.in-page-menu li:nth-child(5).selected::after {
  transform:translateY(12em);
}

.in-page-menu--vertical a{
  margin-left: -1px;
  border-left: 2px solid #eae8e7;
  padding: 0.625em 0 1.625em 1.0625em;
}
.in-page-menu a{
  font-family: 'montserratlight', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  color: #767676;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: block;
  transition: all 150ms;
}

.in-page-menu-vertical a{
  margin-left: -1px;
  border-left: 3px solid transparent;
  padding: 0.625em 0 0.625em 1.0625em;
}

.in-page-menu a{
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transition: all 150ms;
  transition: all 150ms;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="in-page-menu in-page-menu--vertical" id="sticky">
                <li onclick="selectNav(this)">
                  <a class="sticky-menu-link" href="#change-content">Change your content web easily</a>
                </li>
                <li onclick="selectNav(this)">
                  <a class="sticky-menu-link" href="#manage-order">Manage your order</a>
                </li>
                <li onclick="selectNav(this)">
                  <a class="sticky-menu-link" href="#inventory">Inventory management</a>
                </li>
                <li onclick="selectNav(this)">
                  <a class="sticky-menu-link" href="#manage-relationship">Manage your relationship</a>
                </li>
                <li onclick="selectNav(this)">
                  <a class="sticky-menu-link" href="#bcommerce">B2B commerce</a>
                </li>
                <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for the nice solution and its explanation! I enjoyed reading it and really helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS is quite complicated for what you're trying to achieve.

This isn't exactly the same as the Shopify site, but might help you. There's a lot going on. Let me know if you've any questions, or if I've misunderstood you...

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/pdbj86v5/2/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#sticky li a").click(function() {
    $('li a').removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
  });
});
```

```css
.in-page-menu {
  border-left: 2px solid lightgrey;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.in-page-menu li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.sticky-menu-link {
  font-family: 'montserratlight', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  border-left: 2px solid transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #767676;
  font-size: 14px;
  transition: all 150ms;
  padding: 1em;
  display: block;
}

.sticky-menu-link:hover {
  border-left-color: rgba(255, 99, 71, 0.6);
}

.selected {
  border-left-color: rgba(255, 99, 71, 0.6);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="in-page-menu in-page-menu--vertical" id="sticky">
  <li>
    <a class="sticky-menu-link" href="#change-content">Change your content web easily</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="sticky-menu-link" href="#manage-order">Manage your order</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="sticky-menu-link" href="#inventory">Inventory management</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="sticky-menu-link" href="#manage-relationship">Manage your relationship</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="sticky-menu-link" href="#bcommerce">B2B commerce</a>
  </li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The OP wants to animate the vertical line movement between the menu items.

Comment: I have combined your codes with beerwin's codes! Thanks a lot, now it works nicely :) @ovokuro

Answer (score 1):

As posted by beerwin. I made some changes too to achieve the result

1. Added jQuery
2. Replaced **`px`** with **`em`**
3. Translated with respect to the height of the **`li`**
4. Removed the style definition for **`li.selected::after`**

Here is the updated **[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/pdbj86v5/3/)**

```js
$('#sticky li').on("click", function() {
 $("#sticky li").removeClass("selected");
 $(this).addClass("selected");
});
```

```css
.in-page-menu > li {
  line-height: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.in-page-menu > li > a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 2em;
}

.in-page-menu li:last-child::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(255, 99, 71, 0.6);
  height: 2em;
  margin-top: 15px;
  left: 40px;
  width: .2em;
  top: 0;
  transition: all ease-in-out .2s;
  right: 0;
}

.in-page-menu li:nth-child(1):hover ~ li:last-child::after {
  transform: translateY(0px) !important;
}

.in-page-menu li:nth-child(1).selected ~ li:last-child::after {
  transform: translateY(0px);
}

.in-page-menu li:nth-child(2):hover ~ li:last-child::after {
  transform: translateY(2em) !important;
}

.in-page-menu li:nth-child(2).selected ~ li:last-child::after {
  transform: translateY(2em) !important;
}

.in-page-menu li:nth-child(3):hover ~ li:last-child::after {
  transform: translateY(4em) !important;
}

.in-page-menu li:nth-child(3).selected ~ li:last-child::after {
  transform: translateY(4em);
}

.in-page-menu li:nth-child(4):hover ~ li:last-child::after {
  transform: translateY(6em) !important;
}

.in-page-menu li:nth-child(4).selected ~ li:last-child::after {
  transform: translateY(6em);
}

.in-page-menu li:nth-child(5):hover ~ li:last-child::after {
  transform: translateY(8em) !important;
}

.in-page-menu li:nth-child(5).selected ~ li:last-child::after {
  transform: translateY(8em);
}

.in-page-menu--vertical a {
  margin-left: -1px;
  border-left: 2px solid #eae8e7;
  padding: 0.625em 0 1.625em 1.0625em;
}

.in-page-menu a {
  font-family: 'montserratlight', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  color: #767676;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: block;
  transition: all 150ms;
}

.in-page-menu-vertical a {
  margin-left: -1px;
  border-left: 3px solid transparent;
  padding: 0.625em 0 0.625em 1.0625em;
}

.in-page-menu a {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transition: all 150ms;
  transition: all 150ms;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="in-page-menu in-page-menu--vertical" id="sticky">
  <li>
    <a class="sticky-menu-link" href="#change-content">Change your content web easily</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="sticky-menu-link" href="#manage-order">Manage your order</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="sticky-menu-link" href="#inventory">Inventory management</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="sticky-menu-link" href="#manage-relationship">Manage your relationship</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="sticky-menu-link" href="#bcommerce">B2B commerce</a>
  </li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```